# Acer Aspire Notebook dropped and landed on charger adapter

Tags: charging

my Acer notebook was accidentally knocked off a small table onto the carpet floor and it was plugged in, charging at the time. Everything is still working fine and the notebook does still charge, but if I catch the charging power wire and turn it while it is plugged in charging, it stops charging.
Do you think I could carry on using the notebook as it is, as it does still charge, but any sudden movement of the wire will cause it to stop charging. Or do you think I should get the problem sorted out, as I don't want to cause any further damage.
Also what do you think the damage is?

Thank you in advance for any help or comments.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've seen a laptop with a similar problem used for years.  The computer wouldn't charge unless the cable was aligned just so.  Very annoying, but didn't have harmful side affects.

Comment: Thank you for that, it has put my mind at ease somewhat! :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a good chance that the cable is damaged and could cause a short circuit.  This could cause a fire or other damage due to heat.  This is critical if on the "mains" side of the adapter. If low voltage side it can still short.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. So if I was to buy a new power cable, this could sort the problem? as I was thinking the damage would be inside the laptop.

Comment: Maybe it's the power cord, but it could also be the connector in the laptop as well. I would replace the cable first, if the problem persists then I'd replace the connector in the laptop as well.